# Not unique table/alias: 'tbl_users'

Tags: mysql

I have difficulties with my codes in inner join. I need to join 4 of my tables but it has a error:

> "Not unique table/alias: 'tbl_users'"

and when I added alias my table didn't recognized and its attribute.

```
$sqltran = mysqli_query($con, "
    SELECT  `tbl_users`.`userid` , `tbl_applicant`.`applicant_id`,`tbl_payment`.`userid`

    FROM `tbl_users` , `tbl_applicant` 

    INNER JOIN `tbl_users` ON `tbl_users`.`userid` = `tbl_applicant`.`applicant_id` 

    INNER JOIN `tbl_applicant`  ON `tbl_applicant.applicant_id` = `tbl_payment`.`userid` 

    WHERE `u_id.userid` = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'"
)or die(mysqli_error($con));

$arrVal = array();
```

thank you!!.. 
i'm hoping for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be referring to the tables too many times. The lines

```
 FROM `tbl_users` , `tbl_applicant` 
    INNER JOIN `tbl_users`
```

causes the table `tbl_users` to be joined with itself, which is probably not what you intend.

Instead, start with `tbl_users` and then 'join' the other tables one at a time, each time stating which fields you are joining on, like this...

```
SELECT  tbl_users.userid , tbl_applicant.applicant_id, tbl_payment.userid
FROM tbl_users 
INNER JOIN  tbl_applicant  
       ON tbl_users.userid = tbl_applicant.applicant_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_payment  
      ON tbl_applicant.applicant_id = tbl_payment.userid 
WHERE tbl_users.userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'"
```

Other points are these:

1. You have

   ```
   WHERE `u_id.userid` =
   ```

   but you do not include the table `u_id` in any of your joins. Did you mean `tbl_users.userid` ?

   If not and `u_id` is really another table, then you need another `JOIN` to join it to one of the other three tables on the appropriate column(s).
2. You do not really need to have all the back ticks in your table/column names. They are only really needed if you have a table with the same name as a keyword or if you have spaces in your column names. Leaving them out makes it easier to read I think.
3. Although it's good practice to include the table name in your `SELECT` line you do not need to do so unless the column name is repeated in the other tables, as with `tbl_users.userid` and `tbl_payment.userid`. Then using the table name removes ambiguity.
4. By default, just saying `JOIN` will do an `INNER JOIN` and return only those rows whose key appears in both the joined tables.

Incidentally, to answer why you get the Non unique table/alias message, it's because you select tbl_users.userid from tbl_users which you later join to tbl_users again, so it it ambiguous as to which of the two versions of  tbl_users you are referring to the SELECT line.

Sometimes it is useful to join a table to itself, as you seem to be inadvertently doing (it's called a self join). However in that case you should include a new table name as an alias to one of the real table names to make them unambiguous. eg

```
FROM tbl_users
INNER JOIN tbl_users AS copy_tbl_users --  here I am using copy_tbl_users to refer to the tbl_users that I'm joining with.
ON tbl_users.userid = copy_tbl_users.some_id_in_the_table --  Now I use the alias so the table names are unambiguous.
```

The above code, using AS to make the alias, is for MySQL. Although even in MySQL you don't strictly need the AS keyword but I feel leaving it out for the sake of saving two characters makes the code harder to understand so I always use it.